# Recycler view refreshes on data update with no changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that has a list of jobs. The jobs are downloaded and updated in the database. The changes is then reflected in the list and all is good so far.

The data is downloaded and stored regulary in a room database and populated with data binding and live objects.

To avoid that the list is refreshed when the data did not change (overwritten with the same content in the db) I have added a custom DiffCallback for the ListAdapter.

```
class JobDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<JobWrapper>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: JobWrapper, newItem: JobWrapper): Boolean {
        return oldItem.job.jobId == newItem.job.jobId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: JobWrapper, newItem: JobWrapper): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

These makes sure that the objects in the list does not fade in and out when updated with the same content. And also makes sure that data changes are reflected in the list as expected.

The problem is now, that even though the items no longer fades in and out, they will still animate as if they were reordered and back again - so moving a bit.

My question is then: **What am I missing to let the view know that the data actually just was updated with the same content and that it should not make any visual changes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `areContentsTheSame` you're supposed to check all relevant variables one by one.

`oldItem == newItem` is only checking the references (unless you are comparing data classes or have overridden the `isEqual()` method) of the objects which is not what you want. when you check the references, they are never the same so all items count as items with different content. you need to check the content in details yourself.

So do something like this:

```kotlin
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: JobWrapper, newItem: JobWrapper): Boolean {
    return oldItem.job.id == newItam.job.id && oldItem.job.name == newItem.job.name && ....
}
```

or change your classes to data classes.

Or override the `isEqual()` method in your job class and use the the method to compare them.

Comment: In Kotlin `==` is checking `isEquals`, referential equality operator is triple equals `===`. However if `JobWrapper` is not a data class or has not overriden `isEquals` then it will indeed fall back to referential equality and be the source of OPs issue.